# To the border transition is not coming

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm working on image animation on hover I have added border-radius with transition But after adding animation also smoothness is not coming here what might be the issue transition is not working fine.i was applied transition to the pseudo-classes. Is there any other simple way to do this? Can anyone help me out this point me in the right direction. 
Any help will be appreciated.

```css
.image-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-box figure img {
  width: 100%;
}

.image-box figure:before {
  content: '';
  width: 150%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: -25%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 85% 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 85% 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 60px 0 #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  /*  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(.79,.01,.11,.99); */
}

.image-box figure:after {
  content: '';
  width: 150%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: -25%;
  border-top-right-radius: 85% 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 85% 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 -60px 0 #ffffff;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  /*  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(.79,.01,.11,.99); */
  z-index: 4;
}

.image-box:hover figure:before,
.image-box:hover figure:after {
  animation: bounce 0.5s 0.4s;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  50% {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 85% 50%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 85% 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 85% 50%;
    border-top-left-radius: 85% 50%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  100% {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
}

.image-box figure img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-box">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/pr-sample5.jpg" alt="image" />
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The hover pseudo-class needs to be on the same element as where the transition was defined. In your case it was defined in `.image-box figure:before` and `.image-box figure:after`.

```html
.image-box figure:hover:before,
.image-box figure:hover:after
```

You used the `:hover` pseudo-class on the `.image-box` like so: `.image-box:hover figure:before,`

Comment: No not like that once you check my code. According to my code why transition not coming.

Comment: The transition does happen once you do the modifications I mentioned. Change the transition duration to 3 seconds so you can see it happening. However your animation sequence might be the other problem, it does give a weird effect, I'm not sure how exactly you want that effect to look like. Without an example of the desired effect, it is difficult to figure out what you want.

Comment: This effect i want on image https://dribbble.com/shots/5008343-Liquid-Hover-Card-Animations.